# how to start vim with 3 files opened in 3 different windows, two vertically splitted and one horizontally?

Tags: vim

I have an usecase where I have several sets of 3 related files.

I want to open these three files in a layout like this:

```
,---------------------------,
| file1       | file2       |
| #cursor     |             |
|             |             |
|---------------------------|
| file3                     |
|                           |
|                           |
'---------------------------'
```

My question is:
What's the simplest way to configure that layout **from command line**?

I've already achieved that, but I'd like to know if there's a simpler way.

Here's how I'm currently achieving that:

```
vim \
  -O2 file1 file2 \
  -c ':split file3' \
  -c ':wincmd J' \
  -c ':wincmd t'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another, slightly more elegant, way to do it:

```
$ vim -O file1 file2 file3 +wincmd\ b +wincmd\ J +wincmd\ t
```

- `-O file1 file2 file3` opens the three files in three vertical windows, leaving the cursor in the first window:

  [image: 1]
- `+wincmd\ b` moves the cursor to the last window (alt: `+wincmd\ W`):

  [image: 2]
- `+wincmd\ J` moves the current window to the bottom:

  [image: 3]
- `+wincmd\ t` moves the cursor to the first window (alt: `+wincmd\ w`,  `+wincmd\ p`):

  [image: 4]

That said, if you alias it to a command in your shell, then how simple the full command is doesn't really matter. From that point of view, your method is frankly as good as any if it gets the job done.

From a perfectionist point of view, the things that bother me in your method are:

- The outcome of `:split` depends on a number of options so it is not deterministic. You could add modifiers, like `:help :belowright`, but that complicates things even further. I would rather find a different way.
- The mix of three families of commands feels unnecessary and opening files in two ways feels hackish.